# Open set in $\mathbb{R}$ as countable union of open intervals and which version of Choice

Tags: axiom-of-choice

In proving, every non-empty open set in $\mathbb{R}$ is union of a countable collection of disjoint open intervals in $\mathbb{R}$.

It seems to me this result is using some version of Choice(probably AC). Am I correct is it using some version of AC(maybe weaker) or not?

Comment: I think there might be at least one other duplicate. But that one came up first. ***Edit:*** [Found another one.](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1089890/prove-that-open-sets-in-mathbbr-are-the-disjoint-union-of-open-intervals-wi)

Comment: (The short answer, no, you don't use the axiom of choice, because the rational numbers can be well-ordered without using the axiom of choice.)